# How to properly make a api request in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-web

Referring to this article
https://medium.com/solidmvp-africa/making-your-api-calls-in-flutter-the-right-way-f0a03e35b4b1

I was trying to call API from a flutter app. But to make it the right way, I was looking for a complete example and came here. My question is why do I need to create an `ApiBaseHelper` class then `RepositoryClass` then all other formalities to call an API. Why can't I use `FutureBuilder` and a simple async function associated with the API like this:

```dart
    class Networking { 
        static const BASE_URL = 'https://example.com';
        
        static Future<dynamic> getProductById({
        required String? token,
        required String? productId,
      }) async {
        final url = Uri.parse('$BASE_URL/products/$productId');
        final accessToken = 'Bearer $token';
    
        Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
          'Authorization': accessToken,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };
    
        try {
          final response = await http.get(
            url,
            headers: requestHeaders,
          );
    
          if (response.statusCode != 200) {
            throw Exception('Error fetching data.');
          }
    
          final responseJSON = json.decode(response.body);
    
          if (responseJSON['error'] != null) {
            return throw Exception(responseJSON['error']);
          }
    
          final product = Product.fromJson(responseJSON);
    
          return product;
        } catch (e) {
          throw Exception(e.toString());
        }
      }
    }
```

And then calling it from a `FutureBuilder` like this:

```dart
    FutureBuilder(
       future: Networking.getProductById(token, id),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         // rest of the code
       }
    )
```

Can anyone tell me what is the most convenient and widely used way to call an API?

Comment: Its for security reasons recommended  that you have to separate the not only the API calls but all the business logic from the UI. You have to make an abstraction between these.